# How to separate out start and end tags of a block in ANTLR

Tags: java, xml-parsing, antlr

I am currently using the XML lexer grammar defined here:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/xml/XMLLexer.g4

With the given input, I get the following lexer events generated:

XML input:

```
<item>
  <![CDATA[
    My CDATA Block
  ]]>
</item>
```

Lexer output

```
[@-1,0:0='<',<7>,1:0]
[@-1,1:4='item',<16>,1:1]
[@-1,5:5='>',<10>,1:5]
[@-1,6:8='\n  ',<6>,1:6]
[@-1,9:42='<![CDATA[\n    My CDATA Block\n  ]]>',<2>,2:2]
[@-1,43:43='\n',<6>,4:5]
[@-1,44:44='<',<7>,5:0]
[@-1,45:45='/',<13>,5:1]
[@-1,46:49='item',<16>,5:2]
[@-1,50:50='>',<10>,5:6]
```

However, I would like to separate the '<[[CDATA' start tag and ']]>' end tag from the CDATA event so that I can have an event that contains only the contents of this block. I have tried the following grammar which almost works except that because the CDATA block uses a non-greedy match, every single character in the block creates a new event:

New grammar:

https://gist.github.com/alexspurling/2e243b1c806a4482697700ea1f686d44

(Diff: https://gist.github.com/alexspurling/2e243b1c806a4482697700ea1f686d44/revisions)

Output:

```
[@-1,0:0='<',<6>,1:0]
[@-1,1:4='item',<15>,1:1]
[@-1,5:5='>',<9>,1:5]
[@-1,6:8='\n  ',<5>,1:6]
[@-1,9:17='<![CDATA[',<2>,2:2]
[@-1,18:18='\n',<19>,2:11]
[@-1,19:19=' ',<19>,3:0]
[@-1,20:20=' ',<19>,3:1]
[@-1,21:21=' ',<19>,3:2]
[@-1,22:22=' ',<19>,3:3]
[@-1,23:23='M',<19>,3:4]
[@-1,24:24='y',<19>,3:5]
[@-1,25:25=' ',<19>,3:6]
[@-1,26:26='C',<19>,3:7]
[@-1,27:27='D',<19>,3:8]
[@-1,28:28='A',<19>,3:9]
[@-1,29:29='T',<19>,3:10]
[@-1,30:30='A',<19>,3:11]
[@-1,31:31=' ',<19>,3:12]
[@-1,32:32='B',<19>,3:13]
[@-1,33:33='l',<19>,3:14]
[@-1,34:34='o',<19>,3:15]
[@-1,35:35='c',<19>,3:16]
[@-1,36:36='k',<19>,3:17]
[@-1,37:37='\n',<19>,3:18]
[@-1,38:38=' ',<19>,4:0]
[@-1,39:39=' ',<19>,4:1]
[@-1,40:42=']]>',<18>,4:2]
[@-1,43:43='\n',<5>,4:5]
[@-1,44:44='<',<6>,5:0]
[@-1,45:45='/',<12>,5:1]
[@-1,46:49='item',<15>,5:2]
[@-1,50:50='>',<9>,5:6]
```

My desired output would be:

```
[@-1,0:0='<',<7>,1:0]
[@-1,1:4='item',<16>,1:1]
[@-1,5:5='>',<10>,1:5]
[@-1,6:8='\n  ',<6>,1:6]
[@-1,9:42='<![CDATA[',<2>,2:2]
[@-1,9:42='\n    My CDATA Block\n  ',<19>,2:2]
[@-1,9:42=']]>',<18>,2:2]
[@-1,43:43='\n',<6>,4:5]
[@-1,44:44='<',<7>,5:0]
[@-1,45:45='/',<13>,5:1]
[@-1,46:49='item',<16>,5:2]
[@-1,50:50='>',<10>,5:6]
```

How can I change the grammar to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/mathter/fsi/blob/903c435b7b47ade8223fbfe1c9497047baca390a/src/main/antlr4/biz/ostw/fsi/xml/XmlLexer.g4

Comment: Traditional lexer cannot do that since it operates in a context-free manner as you wrote. ANLTR 4 supports "lexer modes" which might help you (essentially it allows you to switch the lexer between different languages, PHP or JSP and HTML for example) - you could switch to "inside CDATA" mode at the start tag and consume anything until closing tag. However it would be great if you could clearly state why it isn't possible for you to just strip the tags from the complete CDATA section as that seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
mode IN_CDATA;

CDATA_CLOSE   : ']]>'                   -> popMode;
CDATA_CONTENT : .+? ;
```

to

```
mode IN_CDATA;

CDATA_CLOSE   : ']]>'                   -> popMode;
CDATA_CONTENT : (~']'+? | (']'+? (~']' ~']' ~'>')?));
```